# Two DNS servers, both incomplete

Tags: dns

In my company we have 2 DNS servers: one for the internal hostnames and one for Internet.

I tried to configure both in my Network Manager, who result in having the two DNS server IPs in my `/etc/resolv.conf`.

If I put as primary DNS server the Internet one, when I try to resolve the name of one internal hostname, it fails, and the resolver doesn't try to found the IP using the secondary DNS server.

In the other hand, if I put the internal DNS as primary, I cannot reach any Internet server from my computer.

Is there a solution to make the resolver to query the seconday DNS when the first one answer with “no such name” or any other DNS lookup error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can use your own name server (BIND) for resolving:

```
zone "." IN {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders {8.8.8.8;};
};

zone "company.lan" IN {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders {192.168.0.1;};
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Probably it will make the trick for now... but what if my company have several domain suffixes? Do I need to define several zones with the same configuration?

Comment: Yes. You need several `zone` clauses for each domain.

Comment: Finally I solved the issue using DNSmasq, that I have previously installed for other reason (as a little DHCP+TFTP server for PXE boot). Your help was totally necessary for investigating in the right direction.

Comment: @JoseLSegura How did you configure DNSmasq for that? What are the steps?

Comment: @Czarek Tomczak For separate zone dns in DNSmasq you have to add  server=/company.lan/192.168.0.1 to the /etc/dnsmasq.conf

Comment: Any pointers to ideas how to archive this on a Mac or on Windows?

Comment: I would suggest to use a small VM with a GNU/Linux distribution without GUI, and use it as DNS server configuring your Windows network interface to use the local IP of the VM as DNS server instead the ones obtained via DHCP. I guess that there are DNS servers for both platforms, but I don't know